# make textbox accept only English numbers or ascii numbers in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, textbox, ascii, non-ascii-characters

How can I make textbox accept just English or ASCII numbers? not Arabic numbers.

I'm working on asp.net C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on keypress and check for input value.

```
function isCharacterKeyPress(evt) {
            if ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

<asp:TextBox runat="server" onkeypress="return isCharacterKeyPress(event)" ID="txtAbcd" />
```